# Undeployed application at context path

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, tomcat

i'm facing an error while trying to run my application, here is the error:

> OK - Undeployed application at context path /gest_project In-place
>   deployment at C:\Users......\target\gest_project Deployment is in
>   progress...
>   deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fnadya%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext1123098247565520222.xml&path=/gest_project
>   FAIL - Deployed application at context path /gest_project but context
>   failed to start The module has not been deployed.     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:187)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:167)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:123)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:208)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:154)

on tomcat log i have this:

> GRAVE: Error listenerStart 11 sept. 2011 23:37:04
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal GRAVE:Error
>   Starting context [/ gest_project] following previous errors

here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <!--Upload Filters-->
    <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
<!--End Upload Filters-->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Theme Aristo -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>start</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!--       FIN         -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/admin-direction.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
   <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

   <!-- JSF mapping -->


  <!-- Map these files with JSF -->

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Clear temp and work folders manually than try again.

Comment: Read further back in server log for the real cause. This information is nowhere visible in the information provided so far, so this question is unhelpful and useless. You're basically focusing on a summary error instead of the real error(s).

Answer (score 1):

(Not an answer)

Your errors are pretty generic and could be caused by lots of different problems in many other places apart from your web.xml. (The application-context, missing libraries, etc...)

You'll have to dig deeper (other files or look below in the same files) to find an error with more relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find whether your application is up and running without any errors when you start the server. With that you eliminate any server configuration and dependency issues.

To do that:

1) Stop your tomcat server. Clean/Backup all log files.

2) If 'manager' app is not enabled, then try to enable it.

3) Start the tomcat server. Observe the start up logs for any errors.

4) If every thing is fine in the logs, then go to app manager 'http://localhost:8080/manager/'

to check whether your app is up and running (started) mode.

5) Now try to access the page or URL.

with this you could pin point the possible areas of error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be also caused by lack of permissions. In my case I gave permissions (to everyone full access, because I'm not sure to who exactly give them) to folder containing Tomcat. This solved my problem.